# What will be the affect of fielddata=true when querying a ~10M document index and more questions

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

1. I have an index of ~10M docs. In each document I have a 'text' field where I put a string in and in the end I want aggregate all the terms inside this field. When trying to do that I only get the entire string.
   I heard only bad things about using fielddata=true. 
   For this amount of documents, is it really such a bad practice to use fielddata=true in terms of memory?
2. Is there a difference (in terms of performance) between using an analyzer in the indexing pipeline (just set an analyzer on a specific field) to using an analyzer as a function (run analyzer on a string, get the results and put them in a document)?
3. Synonyms - I have defined a list of synonyms, I believe I already know the answer but still I'll give it a try, Is it possible to simply update such list of synonyms and that's it? or it's a mandatory to re-index after updating the synonyms list?

Comment: Can you provide example code on first point ?

Answer (score 1):

1. yes the lack of memory is an issue but you should test it to findout how much memory do you need. 10M is not too much doc for 32G Heap memory limit.
2. I didn't understand the question
3. at the time of creating index you should point to list (file) of synonyms words. but after that you can update the list without need to re-index. of course not simple contraction (for that you should re-index). https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/synonyms-expand-or-contract.html

Comment: 1. My primary use of ES is for aggregations, will it less impact my memory in such usage (while using fielddata=true)? 
2. You can directly use an analyzer (analyzar(input_word) = analyzed word) or you can set an analyzer on a specific field (in the mapping) and it'll analyze this field automatically. Is there any difference between the two, performance wise.

Comment: 1. yes. sure. when you use aggregation you can find out how much memory used is for fielddata: http://[master-IP]:9200/_cat/fielddata?v